# JSF : Show navigation history with back and forward button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, back, browser-history, forward

I would like to know how to show to my user at the top of the page, a history of his navigation. Like this:

```
home > register > product
```

And how to implement a back and a forward button in JSF. I read [some topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206953/best-practices-for-back-navigation-links-in-jsf) but none of them really explain how to implement these functions.
I don't want to use some framework for this, I think this is a simple thing to do, which is not necessary to use framework.

I think it's not a good idea do something with `<h:link />` entirely, I'm gonna give you guys an example:

User entering at system:

```
home > register
```

the user register himself

`home > login > register` (there's a link where he/she can register another user)

the correct history would be :

```
home > login > register
```

And not

```
home > register
```

Comment: The `<h:link>` is meant to be used in a loop over all pages visited so far, e.g. `<ui:repeat><h:link>`, as hinted by Luiggi.

Answer (score 2):

What part of the second answer in your link didn't you understand? Using a LinkedList (a `Stack` implemented by `LinkedList` or a `Deque`  implemented by `ArrayDeque` will do the work) and controlling yourself the push and pop operations must not be hard, also create a section in your page to have these links i.e. implemented by `<ui:repeat>`.

Anyway, PrimeFaces has solved part of this job with the [breadcumb](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/breadCrumb.jsf) component, even if you don't want to use a third party library for this job, you can give a look at the [sources](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.2/primefaces-3.4.2-sources.jar) and see how PrimeFaces guys have done this job.

Comment: The second example I understand what you said, but how can I pass the current page to the class so it be able to insert in that linkedlist ?

Comment: It's available by `#{view.viewId}` in EL or `UIViewRoot#getViewId()` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you have each page as its own .xhtml page, then you can just hard code the breadcrumbs. If you want the back button to work well, then in all of your links/buttons you need to add `?faces-redirect=true` to your links.

Example

```
<h:commandLink value="Test" action="blah.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

Comment: Well he could use whatever link. I was just demonstrating how to do the redirect.

Comment: Your code does post-redirect-get while just a get was been sufficient in this particular case. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723

Comment: @BalusC, would be better if I had this back and forward button without been hardcore, cause I don't know the user behavior, so it should be something more flexible.